# Spring Mybatis Polymorphism

Tags: java, spring, deserialization, mybatis

I am suffering Spring-Mybatis Polyporphism problem. Here is the detail:
I have an `Entity`:

```
public class SegmentEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Filter filter;
    // getter and setter
}

public class Filter {
    private String type;
}
```

Where the Filter is polymorphic.
There are some sub-class on Filter, like:

```
public class OneFilter extends Filter {
    private String field1;
    private int field2;
}

public class AnotherFilter extends Filter {
    private List<Integer> field3;
    private double field4;
}
```

As you can see, each sub-class has different schema except `type`.

And the MySQL table `segment` like:

```
CREATE TABLE `segment` {
    `id` int(11) NUL NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `filter` varchar(1024) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
} ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So in order to deserialize `filter`(varchar) in MYSQL I make this FilterTypeHandler:

```
public class FilterTypeHandler implements TypeHandler<Filter> {
    @Override
    public Filter getResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        String json = rs.getString(columnName);
        Filter filter = null;
        try {
            filter = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, Filter.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        return filter;
    }
}
```

and in order to make jackson do polymorphic deserialization, I change the Filter class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OneFilter.class, name = "someTypeName"),
           @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AnotherFilter.class, name = "anotherTypeName")})
public class Filter {
    private String type;
}
```

but the result is that, jackson ObjectMapper cannot deserialize all message.

So is there some thing wrong? What the right step should I do?
Any useful links or docs is helpful.

Comment: Also, when creating e segmentEntity using Controller `SegmentController` like create(@RequestBody SegmentEntity segmentEntity), the deserialization is also hard to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem using jackson custom deserializer.
Here is my solusion:

First I refactor my beans, like:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = FilterJsonDeserializer.class)
public interface Filter {
}
```

and:

```
@JsonDeserialize(as = OneFilter.class)
public class OneFilter implements Filter, Serializable {
    private String type;
    private String field1;
    private int field2;
    @JsonCreator
    public OneFilter(@JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("field1") String field1, @JsonProperty("field2") int field2) {
        // omit
    }
    // getter and setter
    // override toString
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = AnotherFilter.class)
public class AnotherFilter implements Filter, Serializable {
    private String type;
    private List<Integer> field3;
    private double field4;
    @JsonCreator
    public AnotherFilter(@JsonProperty("type") String type, @JsonProperty("field3") List<Integer> field3, @JsonProperty("field4") double field4) {
        // omit
    }
    // getter and setter
    // override toString
}
```

and the `FilterJsonDeserializer` is:

```
public class FilterJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Filter> {
    private static final String TYPE = "type";
    @Override
    public Filter deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Filter result = null;
        ObjectMapper = mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(jp);
        if (root.has(TYPE)) {
            String filterType = root.get(TYPE).asText();
            switch (filterType) {
                case FILTER1:
                    result = mapper.readValue(root.toString(), OneFilter.class);
                    break;
                case FILTER2:
                    result = mapper.readValue(root.toString(), AnotherFilter.class);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not supported filter type.");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

}